# Changing the URL followed by json data dynamically with same value is it possible

Tags: json, url, dynamic, cucumber, karate

```
  Background: 
    * url 'yyy'
    And header Authorization = 'xxxxx

  Scenario: read the csv file
    Given url 'xxxx'
    And multipart file importfile = {read:'datasets/zzzz.csv'}
    And multipart file entity = 'contact'
    When method POST
    And print response
    Then status 201
    * def importid = response.data.import_id
    Then print **importid** **replacing this importid in the below url. this changes dynamically**
```

Given url 'https://' + importid + '/preview'

```
 * def body =
      """
      {
      "import_id": "importid", **replacing here with the values from importid dynamically**
      "entity_columns": [
```

## IMPORT ID SHOULD BE REPLACED IN BOTH URL AND FOLLOWED BY JSON STRING

Background:

Scenario:

```
 * def importid = response.data.import_id
    Then print **importid**
```

Given url 'https://' + importid + '/preview'

```
 * def body =
      """
      {
      "import_id": "<importid>", **replacing here with the values from importid dynamically**
      "entity_columns": [
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you really need to spend some time reading the documentation. Anyway, try this simple example:

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org/get'
* param foo = 'bar'
* method get

* def id = response.args.foo

* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything/' + id
* request { id: '#(id)' }
* method post
```

Note how `id` is derived from the first response and used in both the second URL and JSON body of the POST request.